# How can I cythonize a python file for multi architecture?

Tags: python, architecture, cpu, .so, cythonize

How can I cythonize a python file for multi architecture(x86_32,x86_64,arm64-v8a)?

How can I create a .so file that can work with different CPU architectures from a python script file?